# Excel/VBA removing duplicate rows from multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

Currently I am receiving a monthly dump from one of our databases which contains all of our active public transport subscriptions. It is my task to upload these into SAP, but only the values which are different compared to last month. So all of the new subscriptions should be picked up, and all of the subscriptions for which one of the values in one of the different columns is different compared to last month. If the row is exactly the same, I don't need it.

The file I receive contains 7 columns, column `A` contains a unique key per employee.

I would like to use VBA to compare the two excel files by pasting the file from last month in `Sheet1`and the file from this month in `Sheet2`. I want to find those rows that are equal and remove them from `Sheet2`.

I already found some examples of VBA codes doing this, but nothing seems to work properly. The one hereunder is the last one I used, giving me a syntax error on the following line of code `Do While Not IsEmpty(wsA.Range(keyColA & intRowCounterA).Value)`.

```
Sub CleanDupes()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wsB As Worksheet
Dim keyColA As String
Dim keyColB As String
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Dim intRowCounterA As Integer
Dim intRowCounterB As Integer
Dim strValueA As String


keyColA = "A"
keyColB = "B"

intRowCounterA = 1
intRowCounterB = 1

Set wsA = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsB = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Do While Not IsEmpty(wsA.Range(keyColA & intRowCounterA).Value)
    intRowCounterB = 1
    Set rngA = wsA.Range(keyColA & intRowCounterA)
    strValueA = rngA.Value
    Do While Not IsEmpty(wsB.Range(keyColB & intRowCounterB).Value
        Set rngB = wsB.Range(keyColB & intRowCounterB)
        If strValueA = rngB.Value Then
             'Code to delete row goes here, but I'm not sure exactly'
             'what it is.'
             wsB.Range(Rows(intRowCounterB)).EntireRow.Delete
             intRowCounterB = intRowCounterB - 1
        End If
        intRowCounterB = intRowCounterB + 1
    Loop
    intRowCounterA = intRowCounterA + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

Any ideas?

Nick

Comment: If you tried code which didn't work, you should include it in your post, and explain exactly how it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, still very new to VBA and this site. I updated my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code bellow finds duplicate rows from `Sheet1` in `Sheet2`. It compares all row values in `Sheet1.Row(id)` concatenated, to all row values in `Sheet2.Row(id)` concatenated

At the end it moves duplicates to a new sheet with name pattern `"Sheet2 Dupes - yyyymmdd-hhmmss"` (current date-time)

```
Public Sub RemoveDuplicateRows()
    Dim ur1 As Range, ur2 As Range, dupeRows As Range
    Dim r1 As Range, s1 As String, r2 As Range, s2 As String

    Set ur1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows
    Set ur2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows  'Find duplicates from Sheet1 in Sheet2

    Set dupeRows = ur2(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    For Each r1 In ur1
        s1 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r1)))
        For Each r2 In ur2
            s2 = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r2)))
            If s1 = s2 Then
                If Intersect(dupeRows, r2) Is Nothing Then
                    Set dupeRows = Union(dupeRows, r2)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsDupes As Worksheet    'Move duplicate rows to new Sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDupes = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    wsDupes.Name = "Sheet2 Dupes - " & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hhmmss")
    dupeRows.Copy
    With wsDupes.Cells(1)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Select
    End With
    dupeRows.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply! It seems to work by deleting all of the duplicates. Do you know if it's possible to put the differences in a new sheet instead of deleting them in Sheet2?

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer to move duplicate rows to a new sheet

Comment: Hi, your feedback is much appreciated. I tried the code you provided, however the new sheet is not getting populated and I think I was not clear enough in my explanation. I want to keep Sheet1 and Sheet2 as is, and I want the differences to be written in Sheet3. So no deleting of the duplicates, just writing the unique values in Sheet3.